# Does a Filipina need a visa for a connecting flight in Kuwait?

Tags: transit-visas, filipino-citizens, qatar, kuwait

Our maid is coming from Manila, Philippines, to Doha, Qatar, with a connection in Kuwait. Does she need any visa to pass through Kuwait?

Answer (score 1):

No, she doesn't, according to [IATA Timatic] (http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) but note that she must remain airside and, if the layover is more than 8 hours, needs hotel arrangements.

> Nationality    Philippines
>   Destination Qatar
>   Transit countries   Kuwait
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   In case of transit connections beyond 8 hours, passengers must remain airside and be accommodated in the airport transit hotel.